# is not of type error

Tags: access

I just migrated to a new version in Wordpress, when I tried to save the changes from Administer -> Users and Permissions -> Permission (access control), it returned "is not of type error", can someone have a clue what is it? is it because some table the table type has been changed? Thanks

Comment: Can you check your logs and post the full error from there?